# Enumerations in Delphi with custom values

Tags: delphi, enums, delphi-5

It is possible to declare enums with custom values in Delphi 5 like this?:

```
type
  MyEnum = (meVal1 = 1, meVal2 = 3); // compiler error
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In older Delphis you can do

```
type
  MyEnum = (meUnused1, meVal1, meUnused2, meVal2);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is legal according to this [article](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets). I do recall that in early versions of Delphi supplying values wasn't supported.

It might help to provide the 'compiler error' you received. Also, what version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: This should indeed be legal, see also: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types_with_Explicitly_Assigned_Ordinality

Answer (score 3):

If you have an older version of Delphi (<= D5 IIRC) you can't do this. Maybe you can replace the enum by constants? Something like

```
const
  meVal1 = 1;
  meVal2 = 3;

type
  TMyEnum = Byte; // or Integer or ... - depends on your needs.
```

Unfortunately, the compiler can't do as much error checking for you with this as with an enum type.

Answer (score 2):

As a somewhat ugly extension to the answer by Ulrich you could do something like the following:

```
type
  TMyEnum = (meVal1, meVal2);

const
  MY_ENUM_VALS: array[TMyENum] of integer = (1, 3);
```

and access them as

```
if (aVal = MY_ENUM_VALS[meVal2]) then...
```

Not pretty, I grant you, but at least that way you get a little more compiler error checking for those earlier versions of Delphi.